# Prevent standard paste or force paste values only in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a database/data entry Google Sheets system for a client and have a perfectly setup data entry tab that is being ruined by my clients copy-pasting data into the entry fields. This is primarily an issue with all of the necessarily merged entry fields, which causing them to be un-merged, and then eventually my script fails because the cell addresses change. I can't seem to teach them how to paste values only, so I'm trying to find a way to force the issue. Does anyone have any idea how to write a script, or anything at all that will either block the standard paste, or show a popup to remind them to undo and use ctrl-shift-v or convert their standard paste to a values only paste? I'm happy to share a copy of the tab in question, but I don't think that's necessary for this help ;)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no "out of the box" method to enforce Copy Paste Value. Why not let them paste away in some form, or area where the formatting doesn't matter, and then reference the links? If you have a specific coding question (i.e. how to test if a cell is no longer merged), that would be easier to help with.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of ;) The issue here is that a bulk of the design was the entry form, which they need to be able to enter properly, so they have to stay on that form. I'm thinking that I may need to reformat the form on every edit so that merges come back, colors, fonts, etc. after every edit they make, I was just worried about that slowing things down. Is there no trigger method anyone knows to only fire when they paste? That would limit the checking/fixing part of the code.